# How to tell on Linux (Lucid) if a connection is coming into the server?

Tags: linux, mongodb, linode

So I have an issue where I am remotely connecting to a Mongodb on my linode box, and I am not longer able to access this DB.  I can from my local machine, but when I am on this remote server (where the website runs) it is not working.  I am not seeing the connection come into the Mongo logs, so this leads me to believe that maybe it is being intercepted by a firewall?

How can I watch traffic and see if this connection is at least making it to my linode box?  I am connecting with Mongoid, so if there is a way to prove no connection there too.

Right now the only error I get is a erb view timeout execution error - not much to go on.

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: is your mongod instance configured to listen on the interface this connection is expected to be coming in on?  Can you connect to host:port of it at all from external machine?

Comment: Yes, I can connect to this mongo instance from my local mac with no problem.